# ZVS not working and doing weird things?

Tags: transformer, zvs

I recently made a simple ZVS circuit using 1w 15V zeners (BZX85B15-TR) , UF4007 ultrafast diodes, IXFH36N60X3 Mosfets, the capacitor consisted of a 3S3P setup with each cap being 680nf 250v film caps, the inductor is 100uH. I did my flyback transformer turns in a 4+4 manner.

Previously, with almost the exact same circuit except with cheap amazon parts, I was able to run my ZVS at 12v before it died at 15v cause the zener diodes were fake and murdered my mosfets, I also noticed the freq was very low so my fast diodes were probably not fast diodes? (idk but I made sure to buy the parts from mouser for my rebuild)

When I ran the rebuilt circuit from my 30v 10a DC power supply, it immediately went into CC mode drawing 7 volts and 10 amps with nothing happening. I though it might have something to do with my power supply having a slow startup, so I added a switch which I turned on after my power supply was already on for a time. This time, the ZVS drew 30v at 3amps initially and nothing happened, I noticed the amperage slowly started ticking up and I let it reach 5 amps before turning it off.

After the run I ran resistance checks on my fets with the circuit attached and confirmed they were not dead. I am very confused what could be causing this issue because the circuit was working fine previously with parts that were almost the same spec.

edit: I included a schematic [image]

Comment: To help you, we would need more documentation: a schematic at a bare minimum.  Helpful data to share if you have would be: some photos of the circuit, and waveforms.

Comment: ZVS circuits don't use a flyback transformer.

Comment: zvs circuits can be hooked up to a flyback transformer, and in my case it is currently hooked up to one.

Comment: I added a schematic of my circuit, the overall structure I copied off a schematic I found online and changed most of the parts. I don't currently have access to an oscilloscope so I can't see waveforms.

Comment: If you expect us to analyze and troubleshoot your circuit, you should take the time to provide a clear and complete schematic. You can use the CircuitLab app but LTspice may be even better for switching supply design. It was originally called SwitcherCAD https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/using-transformers-in-ltspice-switcher-cadiii.html

Comment: The resonance that is expected here is between the magnetizing inductance of the transformer, and C1 on your schematic.   What is the value of transformer magnetizing?  What is the saturation current rating of L1?

You wrote: "it immediately went into CC mode drawing 7 volts and 10 amps with nothing happening."  This suggests that one or both of the magnetic components (L1, and Tx) are saturating.

Comment: You wrote: "This time, the ZVS drew 30v at 3amps initially and nothing happened, I noticed the amperage slowly started ticking up and I let it reach 5 amps before turning it off." 30V * 3A is 90W of **input ** power - but how much power was going into the load? What is the load, and how is it connected?   

During this mode of operation, please advise: (a) an estimate how much power the load was consuming, and (b) if any of the components in your circuit getting warm.